# ASP.NET Bundling: Writing bundles to files

Tags: asp.net, bundle

We're developing an AngularJS app and using karma/Jasmine for our Javascript tests. I'm exploring the possibility of running those tests against the bundled/minified versions of the Javascript code, but to do that I'll need to generate a file for each bundle so I can reference it in the karma config file.

Thoughts?